# Laravel 5.7 Listener with Eloquent update

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I have an **ImageSaved** Event:

```
    namespace App\Events;

    class ImageSaved
    {

        public $image;

        public function __construct(\App\Image $image)
        {
            $this->image = $image;
        }       
    }
```

and an **UpdateSearchValues** Listener:

```
class UpdateSearchValues
{

    public function handle(ImageSaved $event)
    {
        $event->image->search = 'Test 2';
        $event->image->save();
    }
}
```

If I now save an entry e.g.

```
    $image = Image::find(1);
    $image->search = 'Test 1';
    $image->save();
```

I get this Exception error:

> Maximum function nesting level of '1000' reached, aborting!

It looks like the code is looped, because my listener's doing also an update. However, it runs and is also saved.

How can I solve this better (without Exception)?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTaac.png)

Comment: You should provide a description of what you're trying to achieve, otherwise it's hard to offer any alternatives to your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created an infinite loop. When you save the Model it is then firing the `ImageSaved` which runs the `UpdateSearchValues` event.

However in the `UpdateSearchValues` you are updating the model again and therefore it is firing the event again and running the listener.